# Clicking font selector in portable Photoshop CS4 in 11.04 causes force quit?

Tags: 11.04, wine, photoshop

When I am running CS4 portable in WINE and I select the font button in the application, it force quits. I do have the microsoft core fonts installed. Any ideas? (It never used to do this until I uninstalled and reinstalled WINE multiple times)

Answer (score 1):

Run `winetricks atmlib` in terminal. I think that should fix this problem. :)